# Condition Variable alternatives (c/c++ on windows xp)

Tags: winapi, synchronization

I want to write a thread which runs tasks from an unlimited-size container of tasks.

While the task-list is empty the thread trying to get a task should be blocked.

Coming from Linux I wanted to use condition variable which will be signaled on task adding and will be waited while the list is empty.

I found that CONDITION_VARIABLE is available only from windows Vista, so this is out of question.
Semaphores are problematic too due to the unlimited-size restriction.

Is there any apropriate subtitution?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need unlimited counts on a semaphore to do this, you just need to signal the transition of a queue being empty or not, and a mutex/critical section to protect the data structure

Comment: Unlike linux perhaps, Windows doesn't support unlimited size containers.  Nor does it have a data type that's large enough to count an unlimited number of items.  You'll have to settle for something more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say that semaphores are problematic?  Linux/Windows both have semaphores with a maximum count that can be realistically be described as 'Unlimited'.

Use James' suggestion on Windows - it will work fine. Init. your semaphore with zero count. Add a task to your big (thread-safe), container, then signal the semaphore.  In the thread, wait on the semaphore, then get a task from your container and process it.  You can pass the semaphore instance to multiple threads if you wish - that will work OK as well.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: I guess that would be the best solution, althogh I wanted real unlimitation and not just "realstic" one. Using this solution, I had to change the design a bit, to prevent the risky nested locks. With Conditional variable I could avoid that...

Comment: 'Real unlimitation' is unrealistic <g>.  I cannot envisage of any system, 32-bit, 64-bit or 1024-bit, where the semaphore max. count could ever be less than the nummber of of tasks in the collection.  On 32-bit, for example, you are looking at 4.2 GigaTasks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a Win32 kernel event.  See [`CreateEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

WaitForSingleObject and CreateSemaphore?

Comment: Or if you have multiple partners, look at WaitForMultipleObjectSex.

Comment: I undertand that to use WaitFormMultipleObjectSex, I have to be in an alertable state, but I've had too many beers :(

Comment: @JohnZwinck hehe...you changed the capitalization on purpose...didnt you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
thats my conclusion:

```
void ThreadPool::ThreadStartPoint(ThreadPool* tp)
{
    while (1)
    {    
        WaitForSingleObject(tp->m_taskCountSemaphore,INFINITE); // while (num of tasks==0) block; decreament num of tasks

        BaseTask* current_task = 0;

        // get top priority task
        EnterCriticalSection (&tp->m_mutex);
        {   
            current_task = tp->m_tasksQue.top();
            tp->m_tasksQue.pop();
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection (&tp->m_mutex);

        current_task->operator()(); // this is not critical section
        current_task->PostExec();
    }
}

void ThreadPool::AddTask(BaseTask& _task)
{
    EnterCriticalSection (&m_mutex);
    {
        m_tasksQue.push(&_task);
        _task.PrepareTask(m_mutex);
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection (&m_mutex);

    if (!ReleaseSemaphore(m_taskCountSemaphore,
                          1,    // increament num of tasks by 1
                          NULL  // don't store previuos num of tasks value
                          )) 
    {//if failed
        throw ("semaphore release failed");
    }
}
```